# Super Palindromes in java

Tags: java, math, palindrome

This code give me a runtime of 269 ms, can anyone help me to reduce the complexity of this solution?

Input: left = "4", right = "1000"

Output: 4

Explanation: 4, 9, 121, and 484 are super palindrome.
Note that 676 is not a super palindrome: 26 * 26 = 676, but 26 is not a palindrome.

```
class Solution {
    public int superpalindromesInRange(String left, String right) {     
        int FIX = 100000;
        int ans = 0;
        long L = Long.valueOf(left);
        long R = Long.valueOf(right);
        // Odd palindrome 1234321
        for(int i = 1; i < FIX; i++){
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(i));
             for (int j = str.length() - 2; j >= 0; j--)
                str.append(str.charAt(j));
            long p = Long.valueOf(str.toString());
            long p_square = p * p;
            if(p_square > R) break;
            if(p_square >= L && isPalindrome(p_square)) ans++;
        }
        //even palindrome 12344321
        for(int i = 1; i < FIX; i++){
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(i));
            for (int j = str.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                str.append(str.charAt(j));
            long p = Long.valueOf(str.toString());            
            long p_square = p * p;
            if(p_square > R) break;
            if(p_square >= L && isPalindrome(p_square)) ans++;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public boolean isPalindrome(long val){
        long res = 0;
        long temp = val;
        // System.out.println(val);
        while(temp > 0){
            res = 10 * res + temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        return res == val;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine what numbers are super palindromes? Btw, you may want to take a look at conventions.

Comment: Please specify what does left and right mean. Even though the definition of `super palindrome` is available online. Please add it to the question statement.

Comment: You could try to make you algorithm to take a super palindrome and use that to find other super palindromes and start with 1 as tge first super palindrome if you mean the definition of super palindromes [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200835/831301).

Comment: Let's say a positive integer is a super-palindrome if it is a palindrome, and it is also the square of a palindrome.

Given two positive integers left and right represented as strings, return the number of super-palindromes integers in the inclusive range [left, right].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the `super palindrome` part.
But, here is a simpler implementation of `isPalindrome`:

```java
public boolean isPalindrome(long val) {

    char[] buf = Long.toString(val).toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0, j = buf.length - 1, iMax = buf.length >> 1; i < iMax; ++i) {
        if (buf[i] != buf[j - i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

By the way, use `Long.parseLong` instead of `Long.valueOf`.

- `Long.parseLong` returns **l**ong (primitive type)
- `Long.valueOf` returns **L**ong (object)

**Edit 1**

I understood your `isPalindrome` method and did some performance tests.

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (long xx = 1L; xx < 100000000L; ++xx)
    isPalindrome(xx); // Your implementation
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms.");

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (long xx = 1L; xx < 100000000L; ++xx)
    isPalindrome_(xx); // My implementation
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms.");
```

**Results:**

```text
1877 ms.
3805 ms.
```

Your implementation is faster than mine.

**Edit 2**

Your algorithm is clean, I have found a little enhancement by moving out of the loop `for` the instantiation of the `StringBuilder`:

```java
public int superpalindromesInRange(String left, String right) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    int ans = 0;
    long L = Long.parseLong(left);
    long R = Long.parseLong(right);
    
    // Odd palindrome 1234321
    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        str.setLength(0);
        str.append(i);
        for (int j = str.length() - 2; j >= 0; j--)
            str.append(str.charAt(j));
        long p = Long.parseLong(str.toString());
        long p_square = p * p;
        if (p_square > R)
            break;
        if (p_square >= L && isPalindrome(p_square))
            ans++;
    }
    
    // Even palindrome 12344321
    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        str.setLength(0);
        str.append(i);
        for (int j = str.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            str.append(str.charAt(j));
        long p = Long.parseLong(str.toString());
        long p_square = p * p;
        if (p_square > R)
            break;
        if (p_square >= L && isPalindrome(p_square))
            ans++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I have performed a performance test with big values:

```java
long left = 4L;
long right = 1000000000L;

System.out.println("Warmup:");
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int xx = 0; xx < 10000; ++xx)
    superpalindromesInRange(Long.toString(left), Long.toString(right));
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms.");

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int xx = 0; xx < 10000; ++xx)
    superpalindromesInRange2(Long.toString(left), Long.toString(right));
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms.");

System.out.println("Test:");
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int xx = 0; xx < 10000; ++xx)
    superpalindromesInRange(Long.toString(left), Long.toString(right));
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms.");

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int xx = 0; xx < 10000; ++xx)
    superpalindromesInRange2(Long.toString(left), Long.toString(right));
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms.");
```

Results:

```text
Warmup:
675 ms.
335 ms.
Test:
372 ms.
204 ms.
```

Execution times are almost halved by instantiating the `StringBuilder` outside the `for` loops.

Comment: A super palindrome is one where the square root of a palindrome is also a palindrome.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found another optimization in palindrome generator.
I use the same algorithm than `isPalindrome`:

```java
long j = 0L;
long temp = i;

while (temp > 0L) {
    j = (10L * j) + (temp % 10L);
    temp /= 10L;
}
```

`Math.floor(Math.log10(i)) + 1)` give the number class (count of digits).
The method is:

```java
public int superpalindromesInRange3(String left, String right) {

    // StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    int ans = 0;
    long L = Long.parseLong(left);
    long R = Long.parseLong(right);

    // Odd palindrome 1234321
    for (long i = 1L; i < Long.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        long p = i;
        if (i > 9) {

            long j = 0L;
            long temp = i / 10L;

            while (temp > 0L) {
                j = (10L * j) + (temp % 10L);
                temp /= 10L;
            }

            p = (long)(i * Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(i / 10L)) + 1) + j);
        }
        long p_square = p * p;
        if (p_square > R)
            break;
        if (p_square >= L && isPalindrome(p_square))
            ans++;
    }

    // Even palindrome 12344321
    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {

        long j = 0L;
        long temp = i;

        while (temp > 0L) {
            j = (10L * j) + (temp % 10L);
            temp /= 10L;
        }

        long p = (long)(i * Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(i)) + 1) + j);

        long p_square = p * p;
        if (p_square > R)
            break;
        if (p_square >= L && isPalindrome(p_square))
            ans++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

The result is two time faster than the construction of palindrome using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this ran in 13ms (sans the printing).  But I know it can be improved by generating first order palindromes, in sequence to start.  But I would stay away from any string based solution.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    if (isPalindrome(i)) { 
        int k = i*i;
        if (isPalindrome(k)) {
           System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
}
        
public static boolean isPalindrome(int v) {
    int k = 0;
    int save = v;
    while (v > 0) {
        int d = v%10;
        k = k*10 +d;
        v/=10;
    }
    return k == save;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate the square root of the super palindrome first. Then square it and check whether the square is also a palindrome.

For generating the square roots you first need a lower and an upper bound. Use the ceiling of the square root of left and the floor of the square root of right. Next try to generate only the numbers that are indeed palindromes. In your example the bounds are 2 and 31. All one digit numbers are palindromes, so you need to check each one from 2 to 9. The rest of the way you only need to consider 11 and 22 since these are the only two-digit palindromes in the range. Exactly how you generate just those I don’t know readily. It may be that you need to look at 33 too only to determine that it is out of bounds.

Generalizing to three digit numbers, four digit numbers, etc., will be a separate challenge, but I feel sure that some pretty optimal solution can be devised.

Also handling your numbers as strings is probably inefficient even though checking for palindromes is convenient. See if you can do your checking or at least your generation in `int` math.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need one for loop (except for the palidrom checking which is going to be inside that loop) starting from left to sqrt of right.

```
    for(long i = L; i<Math.sqrt(R) ; i++){
      if(isPalidrome(i) && isPalindrom(i*i)){ans++;}

}
```

don't know if I understood your question right though